# Reliable and fast FFT in Java

Tags: java, fft

since I don't want to do it on my own, I am searching for a good FFT implementation for java. First I used this one here [FFT Princeton](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/97data/FFT.java.html) but it uses objects and my profiler told me, that its not really fast due to this fact. So I googled again and found this one: [FFT Columbia](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~ronw/code/MEAPsoft/doc/html/FFT_8java-source.html) which is faster. Maybe one of you guys know another FFT implementation? I'd like to have the "best" one because my app has to process a huge amount of sound data, and users don't like waiting... ;-)

Regards.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

FFTW is the 'fastest fourier transform in the west', and has some Java wrappers:

> http://www.fftw.org/download.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: looks interesting, I will check it out later on. :)

Comment: I have accepted your answer even though I don't use it, but many pepole refer to this lib.

Comment: Note that FFTW is covered under the GPL license. (nonfree version available with less restrictive license)

Comment: How about apache-commons' FastFourierTransformer class?

Answer (score 21):

Late to the party - here as a pure java solution for those when JNI is not an option.[JTransforms](http://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms)

Comment: JTransforms doesn't have as nice API as Apache Commons FastFourierTransformer but is much faster.

Answer (score 17):

I wrote a function for the FFT in Java.

I've released it in the Public Domain so you can use those functions everywhere (for personal or business projects too). Just cite me in the credits and send me a link to your work, and you're okay.

It is completely reliable. I've checked its output against Mathematica's FFT and they were always correct until the 15th decimal digit. I think it's an excellent FFT implementation for Java. I wrote it on the J2SE 1.6 version and tested it on the J2SE 1.5-1.6 version.

If you count the number of instructions (it's a lot much simpler than a perfect computational complexity function estimation) you can clearly see that this version is great even if it's not optimized at all. I'm planning to publish the optimized version if there are enough requests.

Let me know if it was helpful, and tell me any comments you like.

I share the same code right here:

```
/**
* @author Orlando Selenu
* Originally written in the Summer of 2008
* Based on the algorithms originally published by E. Oran Brigham "The Fast Fourier Transform" 1973, in ALGOL60 and FORTRAN
*/
public class FFTbase {
/**
 * The Fast Fourier Transform (generic version, with NO optimizations).
 *
 * @param inputReal
 *            an array of length n, the real part
 * @param inputImag
 *            an array of length n, the imaginary part
 * @param DIRECT
 *            TRUE = direct transform, FALSE = inverse transform
 * @return a new array of length 2n
 */
public static double[] fft(final double[] inputReal, double[] inputImag,
                           boolean DIRECT) {
    // - n is the dimension of the problem
    // - nu is its logarithm in base e
    int n = inputReal.length;

    // If n is a power of 2, then ld is an integer (_without_ decimals)
    double ld = Math.log(n) / Math.log(2.0);

    // Here I check if n is a power of 2. If exist decimals in ld, I quit
    // from the function returning null.
    if (((int) ld) - ld != 0) {
        System.out.println("The number of elements is not a power of 2.");
        return null;
    }

    // Declaration and initialization of the variables
    // ld should be an integer, actually, so I don't lose any information in
    // the cast
    int nu = (int) ld;
    int n2 = n / 2;
    int nu1 = nu - 1;
    double[] xReal = new double[n];
    double[] xImag = new double[n];
    double tReal, tImag, p, arg, c, s;

    // Here I check if I'm going to do the direct transform or the inverse
    // transform.
    double constant;
    if (DIRECT)
        constant = -2 * Math.PI;
    else
        constant = 2 * Math.PI;

    // I don't want to overwrite the input arrays, so here I copy them. This
    // choice adds \Theta(2n) to the complexity.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        xReal[i] = inputReal[i];
        xImag[i] = inputImag[i];
    }

    // First phase - calculation
    int k = 0;
    for (int l = 1; l <= nu; l++) {
        while (k < n) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= n2; i++) {
                p = bitreverseReference(k >> nu1, nu);
                // direct FFT or inverse FFT
                arg = constant * p / n;
                c = Math.cos(arg);
                s = Math.sin(arg);
                tReal = xReal[k + n2] * c + xImag[k + n2] * s;
                tImag = xImag[k + n2] * c - xReal[k + n2] * s;
                xReal[k + n2] = xReal[k] - tReal;
                xImag[k + n2] = xImag[k] - tImag;
                xReal[k] += tReal;
                xImag[k] += tImag;
                k++;
            }
            k += n2;
        }
        k = 0;
        nu1--;
        n2 /= 2;
    }

    // Second phase - recombination
    k = 0;
    int r;
    while (k < n) {
        r = bitreverseReference(k, nu);
        if (r > k) {
            tReal = xReal[k];
            tImag = xImag[k];
            xReal[k] = xReal[r];
            xImag[k] = xImag[r];
            xReal[r] = tReal;
            xImag[r] = tImag;
        }
        k++;
    }

    // Here I have to mix xReal and xImag to have an array (yes, it should
    // be possible to do this stuff in the earlier parts of the code, but
    // it's here to readability).
    double[] newArray = new double[xReal.length * 2];
    double radice = 1 / Math.sqrt(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i += 2) {
        int i2 = i / 2;
        // I used Stephen Wolfram's Mathematica as a reference so I'm going
        // to normalize the output while I'm copying the elements.
        newArray[i] = xReal[i2] * radice;
        newArray[i + 1] = xImag[i2] * radice;
    }
    return newArray;
}

/**
 * The reference bit reverse function.
 */
private static int bitreverseReference(int j, int nu) {
    int j2;
    int j1 = j;
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= nu; i++) {
        j2 = j1 / 2;
        k = 2 * k + j1 - 2 * j2;
        j1 = j2;
    }
    return k;
  }
}
```

EDIT: 5th of May, 2022. Well... after more than 10 years I'm publishing the code on GitHub to avoid losing it: https://github.com/hedoluna/fft
Feel free to contribute and send me your opinions :) Thanks!

Comment: Can you please state the license on the webpage? Also, please state how you want to be cited.

Comment: Hi @stackoverflowuser2010, the license is at http://www.wikijava.org/wiki/WikiJava:GFDL so just link to the code, and write my name (Orlando Selenu) :)

What's your project?

Comment: Thanks. Working on Android and need an FFT implementation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you implemented the optimized version already?

Comment: Hi ravemir, yes actually. It's optimized for some small input lengths (8 and 32), but you could easily extend it. I'll post it asap in wikijava.

Comment: reporting a broken link

Comment: Thanky @meetthakkar I'll restore it asap. In the meanwhile you can find it here: https://web.archive.org/web/20150922044939/http://www.wikijava.org/wiki/The_Fast_Fourier_Transform_in_Java_%28part_1%29

Comment: Well... after more than 10 years I'm publishing the code on Github to avoid losing it: https://github.com/hedoluna/fft Feel free to contribute and send me your opinions :) Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I guess it depends on what you are processing. If you are calculating the FFT over a large duration you might find that it does take a while depending on how many frequency points you are wanting. However, in most cases for audio it is considered non-stationary (that is the signals mean and variance changes to much over time), so taking one large FFT ([Periodogram PSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodogram) estimate) is not an accurate representation. Alternatively you could use Short-time Fourier transform, whereby you break the signal up into smaller frames and calculate the FFT. The frame size varies depending on how quickly the statistics change, for speech it is usually 20-40ms, for music I assume it is slightly higher.

This method is good if you are sampling from the microphone, because it allows you to buffer each frame at a time, calculate the fft and give what the user feels is "real time" interaction. Because 20ms is quick, because we can't really perceive a time difference that small.

I developed a small bench mark to test the difference between FFTW and KissFFT c-libraries on a speech signal. Yes FFTW is highly optimised, but when you are taking only short-frames, updating the data for the user, and using only a small fft size, they are both very similar. Here is an example on how to implement the [KissFFT libraries in Android](http://www.digiphd.com/android-java-simple-fft-libgdx/) using LibGdx by badlogic games. I implemented this library using overlapping frames in an Android App I developed a few months ago called [Speech Enhancement for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.enhancement).

Answer (score 4):

I'm looking into using [SSTJ](http://carsomyr.github.io/shared/) for FFTs in Java.  It can redirect via JNI to [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org) if the library is available or will use a pure Java implementation if not.

Comment: SSTJ link out of date... you mean the Shared Scientific Toolbox in Java, now hosted on [carsomyr.github.io](http://carsomyr.github.io/shared/)

Comment: @JasonS I corrected his link