# Fast Fourier transformation in Java

Tags: java, android, fft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reliable and fast FFT in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287518/reliable-and-fast-fft-in-java)

i want to implement a fast fourier transformation calculation in java. Is there any library in java to do calculation in fourier transform and i also want to know about the audio libraries in java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be a duplicate, but you're probably going to have a challenge making a JNI/NDK setup work. Consider a full java solution with [JTransforms](http://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms)

Comment: JFtransforms and SSTJ are also mentioned in the other question, reading past the accepted answer is useful ;-) Also the queston itself already mentions 2 alternative implementations.