# Dataflow Diagram or Pseudo Code for Fast Fourier Transform?

Tags: java, algorithm, fft, dataflow-diagram

I have an ArrayList that has `Double` elements. I want to implement `FFT`(Fast Fourier Transform) on it. However I don't want to take a Java code somewhere else and copy it. How can I find the **understandable** `dataflow diagram or pseudo code` of FFT algorithm?

**PS:** My ArrayList variable is a one-dimensional List.

Comment: There is more than one FFT algorithm - the FFT itself is just a general principle - there are many different ways to implement it. Do you want something simple, or is your application performance-critical ? You could just port something like KissFFT to Java.

Comment: Why don't you want to use an actual library instead of copy/pasting random code from the internet ? There *must* be plenty of *good*, *extensively tested* and *performant* FFT libraries for Java. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287518/reliable-and-fast-fft-in-java) is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Would diagram in this article satisfy you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm ?

I built a Pascal program that was using this method almost 20 years ago.

Comment: I looked at your other questions and wonder what are you doing with FFTs and WAV files? I used to write some software for prosodics research and then got some extra mileage from SoundBlaster control and FFT processing analyzing anomalous sounds from sea vessel drive shafts.

Comment: I want to implement MFCC algorithm with Java. I will get the wav files that includes sounds of animals and my program will say which animals' voices has included at that files.