# Creating spectrogram from .wav using FFT in java

Tags: java, signal-processing, fft, spectrogram

After researching and a lot of trials-and-errors, I have come to a point that I can construct a spectrogram which I think it has element of **rights and wrongs**.

**1.** First, I read .wav file into a byte array and extract only the data part.

**2.** I convert the byte array into a double array which takes the average of right and left channels. I also notice that 1 sample of 1 channel consists of 2 bytes. So, 4 bytes into 1 double.

**3.** For a certain window size of power of 2, I apply FFT from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287518/reliable-and-fast-fft-in-java) and get the amplitude in frequency domain. This is a vertical strip of the spectrogram image.

**4.** I do this repeatedly with the same window size and overlapping for the whole data and obtain the spectrogram.

**The following is the code for read .wav into double array**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class readWAV2Array {

    private byte[] entireFileData;

    //SR = sampling rate
    public double getSR(){
        ByteBuffer wrapped = ByteBuffer.wrap(Arrays.copyOfRange(entireFileData, 24, 28)); // big-endian by default
        double SR = wrapped.order(java.nio.ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();
        return SR;
    }

    public readWAV2Array(String filepath, boolean print_info) throws IOException{
        Path path = Paths.get(filepath);
        this.entireFileData = Files.readAllBytes(path);

        if (print_info){

        //extract format
        String format = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(entireFileData, 8, 12), "UTF-8");

        //extract number of channels
        int noOfChannels = entireFileData[22];
        String noOfChannels_str;
        if (noOfChannels == 2)
            noOfChannels_str = "2 (stereo)";
        else if (noOfChannels == 1)
            noOfChannels_str = "1 (mono)";
        else
            noOfChannels_str = noOfChannels + "(more than 2 channels)";

        //extract sampling rate (SR)
        int SR = (int) this.getSR();

        //extract Bit Per Second (BPS/Bit depth)
        int BPS = entireFileData[34];

        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("File path:          " + filepath);
        System.out.println("File format:        " + format);
        System.out.println("Number of channels: " + noOfChannels_str);
        System.out.println("Sampling rate:      " + SR);
        System.out.println("Bit depth:          " + BPS);
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");

        }
    }

    public double[] getByteArray (){
        byte[] data_raw = Arrays.copyOfRange(entireFileData, 44, entireFileData.length);
        int totalLength = data_raw.length;

        //declare double array for mono
        int new_length = totalLength/4;
        double[] data_mono = new double[new_length];

        double left, right;
        for (int i = 0; i < new_length; i++){
            left = ((data_raw[i] & 0xff) << 8) | (data_raw[i+1] & 0xff);
            right = ((data_raw[i+2] & 0xff) << 8) | (data_raw[i+3] & 0xff);
            data_mono[i] = (left+right)/2.0;
        }       
        return data_mono;
    }
}
```

**The following code is the main program to run**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class App {

    public static Color getColor(double power) {
        double H = power * 0.4; // Hue (note 0.4 = Green, see huge chart below)
        double S = 1.0; // Saturation
        double B = 1.0; // Brightness

        return Color.getHSBColor((float)H, (float)S, (float)B);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String filepath = "audio_work/Sine_Sweep_Full_Spectrum_20_Hz_20_kHz_audiocheck.wav";
        try {

            //get raw double array containing .WAV data
            readWAV2Array audioTest = new readWAV2Array(filepath, true);
            double[] rawData = audioTest.getByteArray();
            int length = rawData.length;

            //initialize parameters for FFT
            int WS = 2048; //WS = window size
            int OF = 8;    //OF = overlap factor
            int windowStep = WS/OF;

            //calculate FFT parameters
            double SR = audioTest.getSR();
            double time_resolution = WS/SR;
            double frequency_resolution = SR/WS;
            double highest_detectable_frequency = SR/2.0;
            double lowest_detectable_frequency = 5.0*SR/WS;

            System.out.println("time_resolution:              " + time_resolution*1000 + " ms");
            System.out.println("frequency_resolution:         " + frequency_resolution + " Hz");
            System.out.println("highest_detectable_frequency: " + highest_detectable_frequency + " Hz");
            System.out.println("lowest_detectable_frequency:  " + lowest_detectable_frequency + " Hz");

            //initialize plotData array
            int nX = (length-WS)/windowStep;
            int nY = WS;
            double[][] plotData = new double[nX][nY]; 

            //apply FFT and find MAX and MIN amplitudes

            double maxAmp = Double.MIN_VALUE;
            double minAmp = Double.MAX_VALUE;

            double amp_square;

            double[] inputImag = new double[length];

            for (int i = 0; i < nX; i++){
                Arrays.fill(inputImag, 0.0);
                double[] WS_array = FFT.fft(Arrays.copyOfRange(rawData, i*windowStep, i*windowStep+WS), inputImag, true);
                for (int j = 0; j < nY; j++){
                    amp_square = (WS_array[2*j]*WS_array[2*j]) + (WS_array[2*j+1]*WS_array[2*j+1]);
                    if (amp_square == 0.0){
                        plotData[i][j] = amp_square;
                    }
                    else{
                        plotData[i][j] = 10 * Math.log10(amp_square);
                    }

                    //find MAX and MIN amplitude
                    if (plotData[i][j] > maxAmp)
                        maxAmp = plotData[i][j];
                    else if (plotData[i][j] < minAmp)
                        minAmp = plotData[i][j];

                }
            }

            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Maximum amplitude: " + maxAmp);
            System.out.println("Minimum amplitude: " + minAmp);
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");

            //Normalization
            double diff = maxAmp - minAmp;
            for (int i = 0; i < nX; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < nY; j++){
                    plotData[i][j] = (plotData[i][j]-minAmp)/diff;
                }
            }

            //plot image
            BufferedImage theImage = new BufferedImage(nX, nY, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            double ratio;
            for(int x = 0; x<nX; x++){
                for(int y = 0; y<nY; y++){
                    ratio = plotData[x][y];

                    //theImage.setRGB(x, y, new Color(red, green, 0).getRGB());
                    Color newColor = getColor(1.0-ratio);
                    theImage.setRGB(x, y, newColor.getRGB());
                }
            }
            File outputfile = new File("saved.png");
            ImageIO.write(theImage, "png", outputfile);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**However, the image I obtain from .wav playing sweeping sound from 20-20kHz is like this:**

**The color show the intensity of sound red(High)-->green(Low)**

[image]

**By right, it should look something like the picture below:**

[image]

I would really appreciate if I can get any correct/improvement/suggest on my project. Thank you in advance for commenting on my question.

Comment: Can you explain your program’s spectrogram image—which axis is time and which is frequency? The colors are hard to interpret, can you use grayscale?

Comment: x-axis is time and y-axis is frequency. red is high amplitude, green is low amplitude.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fortunately it seems you have more rights than wrongs.

The first and main issue which results in the extra red lines is due to how you decode the data in `readWAV2Array.getByteArray`. Since the samples span 4 bytes, you must index in multiples of 4 (e.g. bytes 0,1,2,3 for sample 0, bytes 4,5,6,7 for sample 1) otherwise you would be reading overlapping blocks of 4 bytes (e.g. bytes 0,1,2,3 for sample 0, bytes 1,2,3,4 for sample 1). The other thing with this conversion is that you must explicitly cast the result to the signed `short` type before it can be assigned to `left` and `right` (which are of type `double`) in order to get a signed 16 bit result out of unsigned bytes. This should give you a conversion loop which looks like:

```
for (int i = 0; 4*i+3 < totalLength; i++){
  left = (short)((data_raw[4*i+1] & 0xff) << 8) | (data_raw[4*i] & 0xff);
  right = (short)((data_raw[4*i+3] & 0xff) << 8) | (data_raw[4*i+2] & 0xff);
  data_mono[i] = (left+right)/2.0;
}
```

At this point you should start to get a plot that has strong lines representing your 20Hz-20kHz chirp:

[image: fixed decoding]

But you should notice that you actually get 2 lines. This is because for real-valued signal, the frequency spectrum has Hermitian symmetry. The magnitude of the spectrum above the Nyquist frequency (half the sampling rate, in this case 44100Hz/2) is thus a redundant reflection of the spectrum below the Nyquist frequency. Only plotting the non-redundant part below the Nyquist frequency can be achieved by changing the definition of `nY` in `main` to:

```
int nY = WS/2 + 1;
```

and would give you:

[image: only non-redundant spectrum]

Almost what we're looking for, but the sweep with increasing frequency generates a figure with a line that's decreasing. That's because your indexing make the 0Hz frequency at index 0 which is the top of the figure, and the 22050Hz frequency at index `nY-1` which is the bottom of the figure. To flip the figure around and get the more usual 0Hz at the bottom and 22050Hz at the top, you can change the indexing to use:

```
plotData[i][nY-j-1] = 10 * Math.log10(amp_square);
```

Now you should have a plot which looks like the one you were expecting (although with a different color map):

[image: 0Hz at the bottom]

A final note: while I understand your intention to avoid taking the log of 0 in your conversion to decibels, setting the output to the linear scale amplitude in this specific case could produce unexpected results. Instead I would select a cutoff threshold amplitude for the protection:

```
// select threshold based on the expected spectrum amplitudes
// e.g. 80dB below your signal's spectrum peak amplitude
double threshold = 1.0;
// limit values and convert to dB
plotData[i][nY-j-1] = 10 * Math.log10(Math.max(amp_square,threshold));
```

Comment: Thanks for spending time looking through my code and providing such comprehensive and detailed explanation. I have applied the correction but I think the shape I got is not the same as yours. The extra lines are removed but I got a straight line up and down. I think there might be one more correction you didn't put in the comment. If so, please advise. Thank you much again.

Comment: This is the image I got after applying all the changes.
[Click here to see the image](https://s21.postimg.org/j5el9qzjr/saved.png).

Comment: I think I may have an answer for that. My .wav 20-20k Hz is mono not stereo. I will try to fix that and post the result here. Thank you.

Comment: For those reading this post later, if the file is mono just change 4 to 2 cos every 2 bytes is 1 sample for mono. Thank so much @SleuthEye